# <decimal>.ToString("P3") returns differerent results on Win7 and Windows 10

Tags: .net, vb.net, operating-system, .net-4.5

I have got two boxes: One Win7 and the other Win10 (and also a Windows Server 2012 box, which behaves the same as my Win10 box).

On all boxes there ist .NET Version 4.5.2 installed.

When I run the following code:

```
Dim d As Decimal = 1.23
Console.WriteLine((d / 100D).ToString("P3"))
```

then I get this result on Win7:

```
 1,230%
```

and on Win 10 and Windows Server 2012 I get this result:

```
 1,230 %
```

Note the space before the percent sign.

Could anybody help me out why this could be the case? I double checked the .NET versions and they are all 4.5.2, so could it be something to do with the operating systems?

Many thanks all.

**Update:**

Using

```
Console.WriteLine((d / 100D).ToString("P3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

I get this result on all machines:

```
 1,230 %
```

However when outputting

```
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)
```

on all machines I get

```
de-DE
```

I would have thought the the culture must show something different as different results are produced, but as everything is de-DE I still don't unterstand why the output differs on different operating systems.

**Update 2**

... and this

```
Console.WriteLine((d / 100D).ToString("P3", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")))
```

results in this on Win7:

```
 1,230%
```

and on Win 10 and Windows Server 2012 I get this result:

```
 1,230 %
```

Very strange, same culture, different Outputs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `"P"` format specifier is culture-sensitive, as per [Microsoft .NET Standard Numeric Format Strings documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#PFormatString).

Use the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in the `Decimal.ToString(string, IFormatProvider)` overload to achieve consistent, culture-agnostic results across systems:

```
Dim d As Decimal = 1.23
Console.WriteLine((d / 100D).ToString("P3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

**Update**

The `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` tells the formatting methods to ignore thread-specific culture settings and use a special general culture that is consistent over time and machines.

As per a specific culture being different with different versions of Windows:

[One comment on different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516549/why-does-the-standard-numeric-format-for-percentages-include-a-space#comment37080335_516549) suggests that this was changed between Windows 7 and Windows 8.

However, I think your problem is more philosophical. Culture-sensitive strings will always look different over time.

One thing is the software part - the percent pattern was not even available prior to Windows 7 so your strings may already look different on Vista.

The other thing is the real world and its changing conditions. Imagine this scenario: You may get new grammar rules in your country next year which will specify different formats to be used. Microsoft will issue an update which will adjust the default settings to match these rules. However, at a given point in time, there will be users who will not have the update installed and will get different strings as a result. Some users may not update for years.

Does it make sense for your program to reimplement the culture-dependent specifics or should that be the responsibility of the operating system? Having your own culture rules will make your program look weird as most other programs on that computer will have consistent cultural rules with the OS (unless their authors decided to reimplement the culture as well). Of course, there is also the question of whether Microsoft should have added that space into the percent format between Windows releases. But I'm afraid that ship has sailed years ago anyway and we just have to live with it. And again, it affects culture-sensitive strings which are prone to change over time anyway.

If you really must do this, I guess your best bet would be to clone culture for each thread and set `CultureInfo.NumberFormat.PercentPositivePattern = 1;`

Comment: You seem to be on to something but I am still wondering about the result, could you check my Update in the original post?